# Qt Custom Delegate Crash with no error code

Tags: c++, qt, delegates

I try to follow an example in the book "Foundations of Qt Development" to create a custom delegate.

The goal is to create a table with two columns.
The first is just the row number.
The second column is some arbitrary number but show in terms of a bar style.
How the program just crashed after I run it.

Here is my code:

The MainWindow Class

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);

    Table = new QTableView(this);
    Model = new QStandardItemModel(this);
    dataInit(Model);
    Table->setModel(Model);


    setCentralWidget(Table);

    // If I comment out these two lines
    // the program works well
    // A table view with number shows
    BarDelegate delegate;
    Table->setItemDelegateForColumn(1, &delegate);
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}



void MainWindow::dataInit(QStandardItemModel* Model)
{
    // Fill the Model with data
    for(int r = 1; r < 11; ++r)
    {
        QStandardItem* item = new QStandardItem(QString("0%1").arg(r));
        item->setEditable(false);
        Model->setItem(r - 1, 0, item);

        Model->setItem(r - 1, 1, new QStandardItem(QString(QString::number(r*17%100))));
    }
}
```

The custom delegate class

```
#include "bardelegate.h"

BarDelegate::BarDelegate(QObject *parent)
{

}


QSize BarDelegate::sizeHint(const QStyleOptionViewItem &option, const QModelIndex &index) const
{
    return QSize(30, 15);
}

void BarDelegate::paint(QPainter *painter, const QStyleOptionViewItem &option, const QModelIndex &index) const
{
    if (option.state & QStyle::State_Selected)
        painter->fillRect(option.rect, option.palette.highlight());

    int value = index.model()->data(index, Qt::DisplayRole).toInt();
    double factor = (double) value/100.0;

    painter->save();

    if(factor > 1)
    {
        painter->setBrush(Qt::red);
        factor = 1;
    }
    else
        painter->setBrush(QColor(0, (int)(factor*255), 255-(int)(factor*255)));

    painter->setPen(Qt::black);
    painter->drawRect(option.rect.x()+2, option.rect.y()+2, (int)(factor*(option.rect.width()-5)), (int)(factor*(option.rect.height()-5)));
    painter->restore();
}
```

What is the problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem might be in these two lines:

```
BarDelegate delegate;
Table->setItemDelegateForColumn(1, &delegate);
```

You allocate `delegate` in the stack and pass its address to the `setItemDelegateForColumn` function. However `delegate` is deleted as soon as the execution leaves the scope of `MainWindow` contructor. Thus your table view gets an invalidated delegate. To fix this you need to use a pointer to your delegate. I.e. declare `BarDelegate delegate;` as `MainWindow` class member and:

```
delegate = new BarDelegate(this);
Table->setItemDelegateForColumn(1, delegate);
```

Comment: Or even `Table->setItemDelegateForColumn(1, new BarDelegate(this));`

Comment: @vahancho Yes. It's the problem. Thanks. It is strange that the book creates the delegate in the stack.

Comment: @tom book writers are programmers too, aka prone to writing buggy code.

Comment: @UmNyobe Lol.                  abcdefghijk